# Inequality involving trigonometric integral over $(0,a)$, for $a> 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

> Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha_{n}a = 2n\pi + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $a > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Why
> $$
> \int_{0}^{a}\bigg|(z+1)\dfrac{\sin(\alpha_{n}x)}{\sin(\alpha_{n}a)}\bigg|^{2}dx \geq \int_{0}^{a}\bigg|z\cos(\alpha_{n}x) -(z\cos(\alpha_{n}a)+1)\dfrac{\sin(\alpha_{n}x)}{\sin(\alpha_{n}a)}\bigg|^{2}dx 
> $$

I know that $\cos(\alpha_{n}a) = \cos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) \simeq  1$ when $n \to \infty$. Then, for $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
z\cos(\alpha_{n}a)+1) \simeq (z+1) 
$$
But what about the $z\cos(\alpha_{n}x)$ term on the right side of the inequality?

Comment: I used Maple to evaluate the integrals. It is $LHS-RHS = \mathrm{Re}(z) \cdot \frac{(b + \sin b)(1 - \cos b)}{\alpha_n \sin^2 b}$ where $b = \alpha_n a$. If $\mathrm{Re}(z) \ge 0$, we have $LHS - RHS \ge 0$.